# Truncate tables on databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working with two environments in Azure: Databricks and SQL Database. I'm working with a function that generate a dataframe that it's going to be used to overwrite the table that is stored in the SQL Database. I have many problems because the df.write.jdbc(mode = 'overwrite') only drops the table and, I'm guessing, my user didn't have the right permissions to created again (I've already seen for DML and DDL permission that I need to do that). In resume, my functions only drops the table but without recreating again.

We discuss about what could be the problem and we conclude that maybe the best thing that I can do is truncate the table and re-add the new data there. I'm trying to find how to truncate the table, I tried these two approaches but I can't find more information related to that:

```
df.write.jdbc()
```

&

```
spark.read.jdbc()
```

Can you help me with these? The overwrite doesn't work (maybe I don't have the adequate permissions) and I can't figure out how to truncate that table using a jdbc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) - you need to add the `truncate` when writing:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("truncate", "true")....save()
```

Also, if you have a lot of data, then maybe it's better to use [Microsoft's Spark connector for SQL Server](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/) - it has some performance optimizations that should allow to write faster.

Comment: If I perform the above operation, my table_creation date is also changing. So What's the significance of truncate there. Same thing happens if we use only overwrite.

Comment: when you just use `overwrite`, MS SQL drops tables & creates again, but indexes, etc. aren't retained. when you use `truncate` option, then table isn't recreated

Answer (score 1):

You can create stored procedure for truncating or dropping in SQL Server and call that stored procedure in databricks using ODBC connection.